# How to change R package name created using R 'fusen' package

Tags: r, package

I've created an R package using the R package [fusen](https://thinkr-open.github.io/fusen/). How do I change the package name?

I am aware of tips in e.g. [here](https://www.njtierney.com/post/2017/10/27/change-pkg-name/), but is there anything different or additional for R packages created specifically with 'fusen'?

(How/where does 'fusen' detect the package name?)